# Reload current view after Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the below method which is called on click of Save.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public virtual JsonResult Save(MyViewModel myViewModel)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
        MyProcessManager.Save(myViewModel.prop1,myViewModel.prop2, myViewModel.prop3);
       }else
       {
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        HttpContext.Response.Clear();
       }
        return Json(ModelState.SerializeErrors());
    }
```

The save is done using - `Ajax.BeginForm("MyActionName", "MyViewName", HttpVerbs.Put, null).` The view is strongly typed. Now after successful save I want to bind the viewmodel again so that some of the hidden field values get updated.
Below is the default method to load the view.

```
 public virtual ActionResult GetMyConfiguration(int myId)
 {
   var myViewModel = getMyViewModel(myId)
   return View("MyViewName", myViewModel);
 }
```

How can I achieve this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you can add `OnComlete` ajax javascript handler method to your `Ajax.BeginForm()` helper, return serialized jsom model after successful `MyProcessManager.Save()`, and in you `OnComplete` javascript method parse (`$.parseJSON`) model, returned by controller, and update your hidden fields' values. Something like below:

**View:**

```
Ajax.BeginForm("MyActionName", "MyViewName", null,new AjaxOptions
                           {
                               HttpMethod = "Post",
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                               OnComplete = "complete",
                               UpdateTargetId = "update-target"
                           } ){}

<script type="text/javascript">
function complete(data)
{
    // parse model
    var result = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

    // update hidden value
    $('#myhidden').val(result.prop1)
}
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]   
public virtual JsonResult Save(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         MyProcessManager.Save(myViewModel.prop1,myViewModel.prop2, myViewModel.prop3);
         return Json(myViewModel);
    }else
    {
         HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
         HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    }
    return Json(ModelState.SerializeErrors());
 }
```

Comment: Worked with the above code after adding reference to jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js.